# how to use if, elif and else statement in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 6250 rows and 275 columns.

Suppose I have one column as:

```
Time
0.0
0.0
0.0
18:56.5
```

read the data in with `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')`

I am  trying to:

1. pass a condition that if a row1 has 0, print row2
2. if row 2 also has 0, print row3

I have tried several times, can't get any result.

I have tried follow:

```
t = record['Time'].iloc[0]
t1 = record['Time'].iloc[1]
t2 = record['Time'].iloc[2]
t3 = record['Time'].iloc[3]

if t != 0:
    print ('Start_time: ', t)
elif t1 != 0: 
    print('Start_time: ', t1)
elif t2 != 0:
    print('Start_time: ', t2)
else: 
    print('Start_time: ',t3)
```

it doesn't show any error , only prints `t's` value as a result. it doesn't pass condition.

I also tried:

```
if t <= 0:
    print ('Start_time: ', t)
elif t1 <= 0: 
    print('Start_time: ', t1)
elif t2 <= 0:
    print('Start_time: ', t2)
else: 
    print('Start_time: ',t3)
```

It states:

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: you want to print only those rows that have values other than zero in the column 'Time`?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly what you want, but would not a cumsum do the job?

record[record['Time'].cumsum() > 0]

Comment: I think you can directly call`idxmax` without any loops : `df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df.Time,errors='coerce').idxmax()]` , assign this to start time , or `df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df.Time,errors='coerce').first_valid_index()]`

Comment: You can try using `numpy.select` if you have multiple conditional statements

Comment: Your data is not in a proper `datetime` form, nor are they numbers.  `0.0` could be a `float`, but `18:56.5` is an `object` or `str`

Answer (score 0):

**Loop if statement**

if "if, elif, else conditions" satifies any one of conditions, It doesn't check remaininig conditions. So above code only shows t's value as a result. You have to check all of the values for each if statement.

```
for i in range(4):
    t = record['Time'].iloc[i]
    t = float(t) # t seems like "str" type, you mentioned type error.
    if t != 0:
        print("At t{}, start_time : {}".format(i, t))
```

**Pandas condition**

```
record[record['Time'] != 0]
```

It will show the records that you want.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. This will only work if the time format has colons instead of dot. I have changed 18:56.5 to 18:56:5 (colon instead of dot after 56).

```
df['Time']= pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S',errors='coerce').fillna(0)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Time']!= 0:
        print(row['Time'].strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    else:
       pass
```

Comment: The time is in a very strange format. when `18:56.5` is changed to `18:56:5` (colon instead of dot after 56), it will work, try it out.

Comment: I'm sure it does.  However, that is not the format of the data the OP posted.

Comment: I have made the comment appropriately. I have not seen a time format with colon & dot together, hence i took the liberty update it when i tried the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your question was, how to use `if`, `elif` and `else` in `pandas`

   - It seems like what you really want to do is return values `!='0.0'`
2. Iterating through a `DataFrame` is a terrible idea because it's not efficient.

   - Use vectorized operations in `DataFrames`.  [Pandas: Essential basic functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html)
3. **The data shown, is not properly formatted!**

   - `0.0` and `13:15.3` are not time formats
   - it's all `object` or `str` type, so `t1 <= 0` will not work.
   - `pd.to_datetime` also will not work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '18:56.5', '0.0', '0.0', '07:45.4'],
                   'Time2': ['0.0', '13:15.3', '0.0', '17:03.0', '0.0', '0.0', '07:45.4']})
```

[image]

#### Create a `dict` of `DataFrames`:

- The following code looks at each column and adds a `DataFrame` to `df_dict`.  The `keys` are the `column` names from `df` and the `values` are everything `!= '0.0'`.

```
df_dict = dict()

for x in df.columns:
    df_dict[x] = df[x][df[x] != '0.0']  # .reset_index(drop=True) can be added here
```

#### `df_dict` output:

```
df_dict['Time']
3    18:56.5
6    07:45.4
Name: Time, dtype: object


df_dict['Time2']
1    13:15.3
3    17:03.0
6    07:45.4
Name: Time2, dtype: object
```

#### Combine it all into one `DataFrame`:

```
df_all = pd.concat([v for _, v in df_dict.items()], axis=1)
```

[image]

1. `.reset_index(drop=True)` will resolve index number issues
2. The number of values in each column will probably not be the same, so column lengths won't align.  If the index is reset, the end of `df_all` will have `NaN` values filling out the end of the columns.

[image]